# What is a good default background color for a WPF dialog box?

Tags: wpf

None of the brushes in `SystemColors` seems to fit the bill, and IIRC, the OS theme beginning with Windows XP uses a gradient. Is there a standard OS dialog box background brush or a way to tell WPF that the window is a dialog box and it should paint the background accordingly?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try this:

```
Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}"
```